# How can I set the session in the action method and get the session value in _Layout .cshtml on the drop down on change event in .net 6 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I have requiremnet of multilingual for a web page . based on the language select in drop down the whole pages will change to specific language which are coming from DB for each fields of the page.

Challenges I have

1. How to store session and retrieve in _Layout page
2. how can i pass language Id and the field value in parameter to action methods which can pull data for those fields in the header and footer area and bind those fields.
3. Every thing should happen in a on change event of dropdown.

I have tried the on change event in javascrip and Jquery but nothing help me here

Comment: I would take a look at [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0)